# create nested relative xpath for tag with no attributes

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, robotframework

I need to get the count of `<a>` tag which is inside `<span>` and not anywhere else. I'm using robot framework selenium2library and I cannot use absolute xpath. It has to be relative.

I tried to create nested xpath without any attributes but it's not allowed.

```
<a class="xyz"></a>
<span>
<a class="xyz"></a>
<a class="xyz"></a>
</span>
```

`${count}= Get Element Count xpath=//span[]//a[contains(@class, 'xyz')]`
I expect `${count}` to be `${2}`, but the error is 
`SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[]//a[contains(@class, 'xyz']' is not a valid XPath expression`

Answer (score 1):

You expression incorrect.

1. You don't need `[]`
2. You need `)`, change you `xpath` like this :

```
//span//a[contains(@class, 'xyz')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @frianH pointed, your Xpath expression is wrong, if you want to use class name for match count then you should use use //span//a[@class='xyz'], as 'contains' could be brittle here since you are matching by text.

Now one can argue that //span//a[@class, 'xyz'] is better way to use it but in your case earlier is better approach.

there can be other better way, you need to do some research and see what best fits in your case.